# Rails: Custom ordering and priority for model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

For a Rails project I am working on, I have a model that has an image and a priority attached to it. So it looks something like this:

```
card: 
  -id 
  -name
  -img_url
  -priority
```

The `priority` is a number where 1 is the highest priority (default) and it goes on to 2, 3, etc.

My question is what is the best way to assign these priorities on creation? Should I keep a variable in the controller that keeps track of the priorities assigned already and assigns the next one? Also, these priorities are like to change i.e the card with priority 3 changes to 1 and so 1 must become 2, and 2 must become 3.

What's the best way to deal with this?

Comment: Isn't that just a "position" column, linked with a (jquery?) sortable UI, which would allow the end-user to reorder his card as he wants?

Comment: You could use an auto-incrementing database column.

Answer (score 0):

you can find last number and then add it and check

```
def create
  @card = Card.new(params...)
  @last_card = Card.last
  priority = @last_card.priority
  if priority == 3 
    next_priority = 1
  else
    next_priority = priority + 1
  end
  @card.priority = next_priority
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to take priority management operation to DB and DB trigger is a good solution.

First set unique constraint the `priority` column to make sure another thread cannot insert same next priority number. You can use `max` function to get the next number.

And when priority changes, you change priority of all rows one by one which will be resource intensive operation if done in the rails.